# Question above ANOVA - Long term study

Tags: anova

I hope I am including enough information here.

I am looking at the signal intensity of a tumor over time (calculated by the mean of the voxels). I would like to compare several tumors over an extended period of time (1 year) to see if the signal decreases, where the patient has been scanned every month.

Thus, I have 12 mean values (Scan1 - Scan12), from several tumors, from several patients.

Do I simply use a one-way ANOVA to check if their is a significant change of the mean signal intensity?

My data looks something like this:

`Scan1  Scan2  Scan3 ...
 Mean1  Mean1  Mean1 ...
 Mean2  Mean2  Mean2 ...
 ...    ...    ...   ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is actually an example where you would want to use either a [repeated measures ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeated_measures_design), or a nonparametric analog to repeated measures ANOVA, such as the [Friedman Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test).

Is my attempt to amplify on your data structure correct below correct?

```
Subject Scan1  Scan2  Scan3 ... Scan12
Subj1   Mean1  Mean1  Mean1 ... Mean1
Subj2   Mean2  Mean2  Mean2 ... Mean2
...     ...    ...    ...   ... ...
SubjN   MeanN  MeanN  MeanN ... MeanN
```

If so, and if your mean scores meet the repeated measures ANOVA assumptions (sphericity, normality, i.i.d.), then you can use the canned repeated measures ANOVA commands available in the popular statistical software packages.

If you are not comfortable with these assumptions, then you can use a nonparametric test like Friedman's, which should also be available in your statistical software.

I am making the software suggestions, because calculating repeated measures ANOVA by hand is a chore. Yes it is.

Comment: Great, thanks so much for your detailed answer. You modeled my data perfectly. Yes, ANOVA by hand is something you do once in your lifetime (then rely on software :) )!